# jQuery-ui menu submenu not collapsing on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseout, jquery-ui-menu

I'm playing around with the Jquery-ui menu widget and I'm trying to get some functionality that seems like it should be REALLY obvious... but I might be overlooking it, or maybe they did when they wrote it.

I was able to get the menu horizontal easily enough, and make the submenu come down vertically... but, for the life of me, I can't get the submenu to collapse when I mouseout of the menu. It just stays there until I click something else. REALLY annoying. As a designer, it goes against all of my sensibilities and I can't see a reason for it to do just hang there.

Did I break the thing, or do I need to add something special?
As a side note, I've been fiddling with the Jquery-ui js for a couple hours, editing the menu widget. I tinkered around here:

```
// DEFAULT FUNCTION:
    // Clicks outside of a menu collapse any open menus
    this._on( this.document, {
        click: function( event ) {
            if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu" ).length ) {
                this.collapseAll( event );
            }

            // Reset the mouseHandled flag
            this.mouseHandled = false;
        },
        // I ADDED THIS:
        mouseout: function( event ) {
            this.collapseAll( event );
        }
    });
```

It produced the behavior I was going for... sort of... 
Now I have spotty mouse enter detection for my menu item with the submenu attached. Not really ok with putting a live site up where the menu only works some of the time. Any ideas? Am I doing this the hard way or the wrong way, or is there something I simply don't know about? I'm not the greatest with jQuery, just started in fact.

I'm using a setup that is basically an augmented version of the example on the jQuery UI demo page of the menu widget, so I don't think it's my html that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and find the solution [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-menu-v1-9-0-menu-does-not-collapse-back-to-root-on-mouseleave-from-a-sub-menu). I hope it works with you.

Comment: I'm using the single-file jquery-ui.js rather than all of the widgets as separate files. I'm having trouble finding where to change the code... or even if I can (i.e. this was applicable before some update).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this just took some searching.

I used jplfl's example in the previous answer as a guide and went into the jquery-ui.js file, searching for any functions that had to do with the menu. I found line # 9715 where mouseleave was bound to "collapseAll" instead of calling a function which actually collapsed the menu. I changed it to this:

```
    mouseleave: function( event ){
        this.collapseAll( event, true );
    },
```

And now it works.

So, Yeah. jplfl's answer was definitely helpful, but I thought this might be pertinent as it goes into a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron:
Just search for 'ui.menu' and scroll down till you see 
mouseleave: "collapseAll" 
line, for me it is 11507 (jquery-ui-1.10.3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(“#menu”).menu({
mouseleave: function( event ){ this.collapseAll( event, true ); }
});
```

But I'm sure there is another option.
You may check this [link](http://ealegro.com/blog/bug-jqueryui-menu-does-not-collapse-after-mouseoutmouseleave-event/):